# read data into R

Tags: r, fread, read.csv, readr

The World Health Organization dataset is available here: http://www.filedropper.com/who

When the data is read using `fread` (from the data.table package), or `read_csv` (from the readr package) some variables are wrapped within letter r, and are shown as character type. Like so:

```
"\r31.1\r".
```

I checked the dataset in notepad and indeed it looks weird as these values are wrapped within (' '). However they are numeric, and when the regular `read.csv` is used there is no such problem.

What's the reason behind this? How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

the '\r' is e special character used as a new line delimiter for files on windows.

When using read_csv setting the argument escape_backslash=TRUE might do the trick.

Check [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf#12) for further reading.